# How to handle SaaS reseller that collects payment from customers?

Tags: stripe-payments

I develop and host a SaaS business that bills most customers directly, and that is a normal basic use-case with Stripe.

However, I also have a reseller that handles the billing relationship for those mutual customers. Since I host the SaaS service, all signups and subscription changes run through my software, and I'd like to use Stripe to track those customers, and create an invoice for each one of what the reseller owes us for them. Then I'd like to be able to charge the reseller's credit card once to pay for all those customers' invoices in one transaction. Is that possible?

Stripe Connect seems to serve the general need for handling these types of multi-party transactions. But I don't want to require the reseller to use Stripe to bill their own customers.

It seems maybe it could work if I created a single Stripe customer for the reseller, and then create a subscription for each of the reseller's customers under the reseller's customer resource. But it's not the canonical way of doing it, and I think I'd prefer a Stripe customer resource for each actual customer.

Although it might seem I could just collect payment from the reseller, and then mark all the customer invoices as paid offline but that seems it would double book revenue. I definitely don't want that!

I'm hoping someone might have a suggestion about the best way to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of questions are probably better suited for the Stripe support team, as they’ll be able to advise you on your business model and if there are any edge cases or unknowns you should be aware of: https://support.stripe.com/contact